# What do I need to include to use OpenClipboard()?

Tags: c++, windows, clipboard

I wrote a short program do test out the `OpenClipboard` function. I copied from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/14349/) and it doesn't look like you need to include anything. I am programming with notepad and command prompt, so I don't have a third party program telling me what's wrong. The error messages are simply that all the stuff used in the code snippet isn't declared in this scope:

```
programm1.cpp: In function 'void toClipboard(const string&)':
programm1.cpp:65:17: error: 'OpenClipboard' was not declared in this scope
  OpenClipboard(0);
                 ^
programm1.cpp:66:17: error: 'EmptyClipboard' was not declared in this scope
  EmptyClipboard();
                 ^
programm1.cpp:67:2: error: 'HGLOBAL' was not declared in this scope
  HGLOBAL hg=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,s.size());
  ^
programm1.cpp:67:10: error: expected ';' before 'hg'
  HGLOBAL hg=GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE,s.size());
          ^
programm1.cpp:68:7: error: 'hg' was not declared in this scope
  if (!hg){
       ^
programm1.cpp:69:18: error: 'CloseClipboard' was not declared in this scope
   CloseClipboard();
                  ^
programm1.cpp:72:20: error: 'hg' was not declared in this scope
  memcpy(GlobalLock(hg),s.c_str(),s.size());
                    ^
programm1.cpp:72:22: error: 'GlobalLock' was not declared in this scope
  memcpy(GlobalLock(hg),s.c_str(),s.size());
                      ^
programm1.cpp:72:42: error: 'memcpy' was not declared in this scope
  memcpy(GlobalLock(hg),s.c_str(),s.size());
                                          ^
programm1.cpp:73:17: error: 'GlobalUnlock' was not declared in this scope
  GlobalUnlock(hg);
                 ^
programm1.cpp:74:19: error: 'CF_TEXT' was not declared in this scope
  SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,hg);
                   ^
programm1.cpp:74:29: error: 'SetClipboardData' was not declared in this scope
  SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT,hg);
                             ^
programm1.cpp:75:17: error: 'CloseClipboard' was not declared in this scope
  CloseClipboard();
                 ^
programm1.cpp:76:15: error: 'GlobalFree' was not declared in this scope
  GlobalFree(hg);
               ^
```

Comment: `#include <windows.h>`; you'll also need to link against `user32.lib` and `kernel32.lib`, as specified in the documentation of the functions you are using (at the bottom).

Comment: @MatteoItalia thanks ^^ that was the mssing line i was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`OpenClipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation explains that the header file to use is

> Winuser.h (include Windows.h)

Comment: Also, don't forget the import libraries.